# Cannot json_decode a GET parameter

Tags: php, ajax, json

All,

I'm trying to pass a stringified json object as a GET parameter but the receiving URL seems unable to decode it, I am not sure why.

Here is the relevant code:

Client side Json object production (works fine):

```
function createJson(){
// This works fine.  It creates a json objects with three elements, the third being an array.
//(omitted code for brevity)
  return jsonData;
}
```

Client side ajax call (works fine):

```
function recordSetGet(jsonData){
  request = createRequest();
  var rawSet=JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  var encodedSet=encodeURIComponent(rawSet);
  var params="set="+encodedSet;
  var url= "Ajax_recordSetGet.php?"+params;
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){}
  request.send(null);
}
```

This yield the following URL: `Ajax_recordSetGet.php?set=%7B%22setTitle%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22setTags%22%3A%22test%20%22%2C%22set%22%3A%5B%7B%22first%22%3A%22Joe%22%2C%22last%22%3A%22Doe%22%2C%22checked%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%7D"`

Server side treatment:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');  
if(!session_id()){
  session_start();
}
if(isset($_GET['set'])){
  $set=$_GET['set'];//This is the URI encoded string
  var_dump ($set);
  var_dump (json_decode($set));
  var_dump ("Json last error is ".json_last_error());
}
?>
```

The result of the var_dumps are:
`string '{"setTitle":"test","setTags":"test ","set":[{"first":"Joe","last":"Doe","checked":true}]}"' (length=90)`
`null`
`string 'Json last error is 4' (length=20)`

So why is `json_decode()` failing here?  The `json_last_error()` result suggests a syntax error.

**Edit:  Note that json_decode also fails if I send a non encoded string:**
If I build the param string without encoding it like this:

```
var rawSet=JSON.stringify(jsonData);
var params="set="+rawSet;
var url= "Ajax_recordSetGet.php?"+params;
```

Then the URL becomes `Ajax_recordSetGet.php?set={"setTitle":"test","setTags":"test ","set":[{"first":"Joe","last":"Doe","checked":true}]}"`

And the receiving URL var_dump yield the same error:
`string '{"setTitle":"test","setTags":"test ","set":[{"first":"Joe","last":"Doe","checked":true}]}"' (length=90)`
`null`
`string 'Json last error is 4' (length=20)`

Comment: Please get to know [The SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: **TL;DR**. Try making your question more concise. If we need more, we'll ask.

Comment: That is a lot of code that I didn't read.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant (I hope...) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but you have a trailing double quote in your URL that messes up the JSON decode process.

```
...%7D%5D%7D"   <- Trailing double quote
```

This quote also shows up in your dump of the set variable:

```
...true}]}"' (length=90) <- double quote is inside the string, the single quote is part of the var_dump output.
```

This double quote must be introduced in the Javascript code, although I cannot see a spot where that should happen. But your debugging should take place in that part of the system.

Note that you MUST NOT urldecode the string passed as the "set" parameter, as PHP has done  the decoding for you already. But with the trailing double quote you cannot call `json_decode()`.

As a quick proof of concept, try using `$set = rtrim($set, '"')` in your PHP code before decoding to remove that quote character.

Comment: Right before the first double quote is a backslash.

Comment: You're right there's a double-quote at the end of the URL that as nothing to do here....  When I manually remove it, json_decode works fine.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

> **The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.**

Try a different way. I suggest base64-encoding the json string.

Instead of this:

```
var rawSet=JSON.stringify(jsonData);
var encodedSet=encodeURIComponent(rawSet);
var params="set="+encodedSet;
var url= "Ajax_recordSetGet.php?"+params;
```

do this:

```
var rawSet=JSON.stringify(jsonData);
var encodedSet=btoa(rawSet);
var params="set="+encodedSet;
var url= "Ajax_recordSetGet.php?"+params;
```

But pay attention to the [caveats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.btoa)!

And in your serverside:

```
$decodedSet=json_decode(base64_decode($set));
```

Comment: Why?  Also, note that I try `json_decode` both on the raw `$_GET` param and on the decoded version.  Neither work.

Comment: It's a common complaint in php. Php just implemented it that way. I don't like it, but it's a wasps nest.

Comment: Php is mangling your urlencoded get parameter. There's no way around that.  So use a different encoding mechanism. That's the heart of my answer.

Comment: Would I need to encode if it were a POST variable?  I need to find a solution that works for UTF-8 non-Latin characters.

Comment: Sure! POST is unaffected.

Comment: POST also needs some sort of encoding. If you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the post body looks exactly like the query string, including the urlencoding part. If you choose to use `multipart/form-data`, you'd have to format a proper multipart mime message. Otherwise PHP will not decode the data and put it into `$_POST`.